# When I run: php artisan db:seed. I get his output: Cannot access empty property

Tags: php, laravel

UsersTapleSeeder.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory('App\User', 50)->create();
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    protected $toTruncate = ['users'];

    public function run()
    {



        foreach ($this-> $toTruncate as $table)
        {
            DB::table('users')->truncate();


        }


        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

ModelFactory.php:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define all of your model factories. Model factories give
| you a convenient way to create models for testing and seeding your
| database. Just tell the factory how a default model should look.
|
*/

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'body' => $faker->sentences(),
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

My users table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

I tried migrate, migrate rollback, composer dump-autoload.
It was working until I added the body column, after that even when I delete it.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: Can you share your `User` model?

Comment: this is the full error :[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Cannot access empty property

Comment: `User.php    
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'body',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this-> $toTruncate` in your seeder is causing that error.  Change it to:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    protected $toTruncate = ['users'];

    public function run()
    {
        foreach ($this->toTruncate as $table)
        {
            DB::table($table)->truncate();
        }


        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```